# Form submit POST renders page before submit handler is called

Tags: 7, redirection, forms

I have a search form in the header that is simply adding a search term to the current URL. If you are on `example.com/list-page` and submit a search, it just sends you to `example.com/list-page?search=my-term-here`.

When I submit the form, I've noticed that the full page has to be rendered before the form's submit handler is called. Since the search modifies the current list page's results, it seems redundant when submitting a search for "my-term-here" on `example.com/list-page` to have to render `example.com/list-page` again before the submit handler is called and then render the version I actually want: `example.com/list-page?search=my-term-here`.

I've hacked around this by doing this in my form:

```
// Set to the current path so we can redirect back there after submit.
$form['submission_path'] = array(
  '#type' => 'hidden',
  '#default_value' => current_path(),
  '#weight' => -100,
);

$form['#action'] = url('search-callback');
```

The search-callback does nothing:

```
function mymodule_search_callback() {
  return '';
}
```

The submit handler then does a redirect like this to get back to `example.com/list-page?search=my-term-here`.

```
// Redirect back to the page that submitted the search.
$form_state['redirect'] = array(
  $form_state['values']['submission_path'],
  array(
    'query' => array(
      'search' => urlencode($search-term),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Is there a better way to handle this? Can the form's submit handler be called before rendering the page the form is posting to?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a submit callback that will handle the redirect:

```
 $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_search_callback'
```

And in that callback:

```
function mymodule_search_callback() {
   $form_state['redirect'] = current_path() . and your urlencoded serch term;
}
```

Messing with `$form['#action'`] is not the right way to do it.